# Attempting to vectorize R function for Improved Speed

Tags: r, performance

I've been chipping away at some code to improve its speed. The best I've been able to do so far is as shown in the reproducible example below, but I am still using two loops. In particular, the final line with the two `sapply()` is functionally what I want, but not computationally the most efficient here in R.

Tossing this out to the community to learn if anyone sees a computational improvement and still returns the object `poly.pr` in the form returned by the code now.

This code is seemingly fast enough when run only once. However, in larger problems it increases as the dimensions `X2` and `nds` increase. Furthermore, this code is executed many times as it lives inside an optimization procedure. So, finding ways to eek out the fastest time here will be really helpful.

```
GRM <- function(theta, d, score, a, D = 1.7, machineValue = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)){
    maxD <- length(d)
    pos1 <- which(score == 0)
    pos2 <- which(score == maxD)
    pos3 <- which(score > 0 & score < maxD)

    pr.1 <- 1/(1 + exp(D*a*(theta - d[(score[pos1]+1)])))
    pr.2 <- 1/(1 + exp(-D*a*(theta - d[score[pos2]])))
    pr.3 <- 1/(1 + exp(D*a*(theta - d[(score[pos3]+1)]))) - 1/(1 + exp(D*a*(theta - d[score[pos3]])))

    ### Now put them back together in order
    pr <- numeric(length(score))
    pr[pos1] <- pr.1
    pr[pos2] <- pr.2
    pr[pos3] <- pr.3
    ind1 <- which(pr > 1 - machineValue)
    ind2 <- which(pr < machineValue)
    if (any(ind1)) 
        pr[ind1] <- 1 - machineValue
    if (any(ind2))  
        pr[ind2] <- machineValue
    pr
}

X2 <- cbind(sample(0:2,3000,replace=T), sample(0:3,3000,replace=T))
I <- ncol(X2)
d.params <- list(c(-1.84, 0.22), c(-1.53, -0.43, 2.55))
a.params <- c(1,1.5)
nds <- c(-3,0,3)

### Working to improve speed here by removing loop if possible
poly.pr <- exp(sapply(1:length(nds), function(j) rowSums(log(sapply(1:I, function(i) GRM(nds[j],d.params[[i]],X2[,i],a.params[i],1))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options. The first is to simply speed up the current version of `GRM` by frontloading the calculations involving `log` and `exp` (and `pmin` and `pmax` instead of comparisons) then using indexing:

```
GRM2 <- function(theta, d, score, a, D = 1.7, machineValue = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) {
  pr <- 1/(1 + exp(D*a*(theta - d)))
  pr <- log(
    pmax(
      pmin(
        c(
          pr[1],
          diff(pr),
          1/(1 + exp(-D*a*(theta - d[length(d)])))
        ),
        1 - machineValue
      ),
      machineValue
    )
  )
  pr[score + 1L]
}
```

The second option builds on the first, but uses `outer` to avoid the loop over `nds`:

```
GRM3 <- function(theta, d, score, a, D = 1.7, machineValue = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) {
  pow <- D*a*outer(d, theta, "-")
  pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-pow))
  pr <- log(
    pmax(
      pmin(
        rbind(
          pr[1,],
          diff(pr),
          1/(1 + exp(pow[length(d),]))
        ),
        1 - machineValue
      ),
      machineValue
    )
  )
  c(pr[score + 1L,])
}
```

The final option is the same as the second, but uses `Rfast::rowprods` instead of `exp(rowSums(log(`:

```
library(Rfast) # for `rowprods`

GRM4 <- function(theta, d, score, a, D = 1.7, machineValue = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) {
  pow <- D*a*outer(d, theta, "-")
  pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-pow))
  pr <- pmax(
    pmin(
      rbind(
        pr[1,],
        diff(pr),
        1/(1 + exp(pow[length(d),]))
      ),
      1 - machineValue
    ),
    machineValue
  )
  c(pr[score + 1L,])
}
```

Benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  poly.pr = exp(sapply(1:length(nds), function(j) rowSums(log(sapply(1:I, function(i) GRM(nds[j], d.params[[i]], X2[,i], a.params[i], 1)))))),
  poly.pr2 = exp(sapply(1:length(nds), function(j) rowSums(sapply(1:I, function(i) GRM2(nds[j], d.params[[i]], X2[,i], a.params[i], 1))))),
  poly.pr3 = matrix(exp(rowSums(sapply(1:I, function(i) GRM3(nds, d.params[[i]], X2[,i], a.params[i], 1)))), ncol = length(nds)),
  poly.pr4 = matrix(rowprods(sapply(1:I, function(i) GRM4(nds, d.params[[i]], X2[,i], a.params[i], 1))), ncol = length(nds)),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>      expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>   poly.pr 10.169781 7.387566 6.543169 7.210486 6.794433 1.400273   100
#>  poly.pr2  2.890739 2.132149 2.024770 2.074921 2.031143 1.036986   100
#>  poly.pr3  2.266856 1.856143 1.813469 1.823121 1.747661 1.185563   100
#>  poly.pr4  1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

I suspect the gains will be even more pronounced as the dimensions of `nds` and `X2` increase.

Comment: @dhc, see the update for a third (and faster) option.